# Unable to retrieve data from Mysql in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, dictionary

I am working on a dictionary project in Java on Netbeans. I have two classes here:

"dictionary.java" where the main method is

"DictionaryGuiController.java" where GUI code is constructed with javafx platform

I connected the database and project with JDBC driver and using these codes in main method:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/world", "root", "root");
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM country");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("code") + ":" + rs.getString("name"));
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
}
```

Here I created a connection object as `conn` to create statements and executing the SQL query.
I want to retrieve data from a sample database in Mysql called "world". With this code I am able to retrieve data in a small project that has only one class and main method. But in this project when I run the program I see the GUI interface but I can not see any results in the console, it keeps saying:

**Executing C:\Users\Bar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Dictionary\dist\run414351490\Dictionary.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre/bin/java**

and program never stops until program exits.

Here is the complete code of the classes:

`Dictionary.java`:

```
package dictionary;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.sql.*;


public class Dictionary extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DictionaryGui.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/world", "root", "root");
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM country");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("code") + ":" + rs.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

    }

}
```

`DictionaryGuiController.java`:

```
package dictionary;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class DictionaryGuiController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TextField searchfield;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonsearch;
    @FXML
    private TextArea listview;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        listview.setText(searchfield.getText());
    }

}
```

What could be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you get the data from db or not...

Comment: I think you forgot to register the driver for mysql. Try using **Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")** before making connection to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick things that it could be. First, is your instance of MySQL already running? Secondly, I tend to do all my database connection stuff outside the main method. So I will have a method in the controller class called initDB() or connectToDB() and I put the code in there.

The convention I've seen for the main() method in JavaFX programs is that launch() is the only method called. I could be wrong, but check those two things and see if you have any luck.